# Overall equilibrium expression for competitive equilibria

Tags: equilibrium, surface-chemistry, adsorption

I have a case where I have two reactions that depend on a common reactant. The reactions can be written as:

I) $\ce{A + B <=> AB}$

II) $\ce{A + C <=> AC}$

We can thus write equilibrium expressions for both reactions:

I) $K_\mathrm{I} = \frac{[\ce{AB}]}{[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]}$

II) $K_\mathrm{II} = \frac{[\ce{AC}]}{[\ce{A}][\ce{C}]}$

How can I combine these equations to get an equation that relates the equilibrium concentration of B to that of C?

Secondarily, can this be extended to give an equation that relates the equilibrium concentrations of B and C to the initial concentrations of A, B and C?

I already know the equilibrium and rate constants for both reactions in isolation. If it is relevant, A is a solid with a fixed number of surface sites, to which B and  are adsorbed. B and C are in aqueous solution.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/simultaneous-equilibria touches on the issue, but there are differences in what is already known. Moreover, this is a heterogeneous reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so essentially we have $[A],[B],[C],[AB],\text{ and }[AC]$, and a few equations: three conservation laws and two equilibrium constants.
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
[A]+[AB]+[AC] & = A_0\\
[B]+[AB] & = B_0\\
[C]+[AC] & = C_0\\
{[AB]\over[A][B]}& =K_1 \\
{[AC]\over[A][C]}& =K_2
\end{align}
\right.$$
With 5 unknowns and 5 equations, this should be solvable (because the *nature* manages to solve it somehow, if not for other reason). There is no guarantee, however, that the solution will be *nice*. Indeed, if we deal with the system exactly as it stands now, it is equivalent to a certain 4th degree algebraic equation which is better solved numerically.

Things get somewhat more manageable if we may disregard something. For example, if A is a relatively minor component, so that $[A]<<[B]$, then we may assume $[B]\approx B_0$ (and the same for C). All of a sudden, the problem becomes *linear*:
$$[AB]=K_1[A]B_0 \\
[AC]=K_2[A]C_0 \\
[A]+K_1[A]B_0+K_2[A]C_0=A_0
$$
which yields
$$
[AB]={K_1B_0\over1+K_1B_0+K_2C_0} \\
[AC]={K_2C_0\over1+K_1B_0+K_2C_0}
$$

Whether or not this approximation is realistic in your particular case is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Note that since both AB and AC affect the concentrations of B and C, it's hard to get a relationship between B and C that doesn't involve these species. You can express the relationship in terms of ratios though.

$$ [\mathrm{A}] = \frac{[\mathrm{AB}]}{[\mathrm{B}]K_{\mathrm{I}}} $$
$$ [\mathrm{A}] = \frac{[\mathrm{AC}]}{[\mathrm{C}]K_{\mathrm{II}}} $$

$$ \frac{[\mathrm{AB}]}{[\mathrm{B}]K_{\mathrm{I}}} = \frac{[\mathrm{AC}]}{[\mathrm{C}]K_{\mathrm{II}}} $$

$$ \frac{[\mathrm{B}]}{[\mathrm{C}]} = \frac{K_{\mathrm{II}}}{K_{\mathrm{I}}}\frac{[\mathrm{AB}]}{[\mathrm{AC}]}$$